# Windows won't recognise my microphone

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, microphone, audio-recording

I have tried both my microphones and both of them are not recognised on my laptop. I have Windows 8.1 64 bit. Please help. I know that my microphone works as it works on my phone.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “not recognized”. How do you connect the microphone? Is sound output working properly?

Comment: Not recognised means when I go to "Sound", "Mic in front panel (black)" says it's not plugged in after I've plugged it in. I connect the microphone in the 2 in 1 socket using an audio splitter but I don't need an audio splitter for my headphones that has a microphone built in (headset). Sound output works as I can listen to music with headphones.

Comment: Are you sure it’s a combined jack? Is it a notebook?

Comment: Yes it is a combined jack but my headset microphone isn't recognised when I use an audio splitter, and my microphone isn't recognised when I use an audio splitter.

Comment: Please provide the exact make and model of whatever you plug your devices into. What makes you think it’s combined? The manual, a headset icon next to it perhaps?

Comment: It is combined because there's only one socket for audio, not two. HP Pavilion 15-p247sa L2W58EA#ABU http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04548064